# Slope function error(sort-of)... again

Tags: javascript, html, math, processing, p5.js

Well this one feels tough...
**BEFORE YOU READ** 
p5js.org
This is p5.js library

Earlier I made a slope function with some help.

```
function graphY(num,cHI){
    var GsetR = cHI-num;
    return(GsetR);
};

function slope(x1,y1,x2,y2,ex,direction){
    //direction left or right? mirror flips for right
    var gg1 = x2-x1;
    var gg2 = y2-y1;
    var ggs = gg2/gg1;
    var ggsR = gg1/gg2;
    console.log(ggsR);
    if(direction == "right"){
        return(ggs);
    }
    if(direction == "left"){
        return(-ggs);
    }
};


function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000,650);


}

var slipX= 100;
var slipY= 500;
function draw() {





  background(204);
  fill(0,0,0);
  stroke(0,0,0);
  strokeWeight(2)
  ellipse(slipX,slipY,20,20);
  slipY += slope(100,500,50,200,slipX,"left"); // I WANT THE BALL TO GO TO THE LEFT
  line(100,500,50,200);
  slipX++;
  text(slipY,20,20);



}
```

Although it works fine on the "right" mode It doesn't work for left. And this is where the "sort-of bit comes in"

I need the negative RECIPROCAL of ggs not just negative but I checked all documentations and couldn't find out how.
ggsR doesnt work...

**Is there any way to get the reciprocal of ggs?**

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check the `direction` before you do your calculations? Something like:

```
function slope(x1,y1,x2,y2,ex,direction){

    if(direction == "right"){
      var gg1 = x2-x1;
      var gg2 = y2-y1;
      var ggs = gg2/gg1;
      var ggsR = gg1/gg2;
      console.log(ggsR);
      return(ggs);
    }
    else if(direction == "left"){
      //do something else
    }
};
```